# Given 3 sets $|A|=6, |B|=4, |C|=3$ and $C \subseteq B$. Calculate the size of the set: $\{f\in A\to B$ $| C\subseteq Imf\}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

Given 3 sets $|A|=6, |B|=4, |C|=3$ and $C \subseteq B$. Calculate the size of the set:

$\{f\in A\to B$ $| C\subseteq Imf\}$

Please let me know if you have any idea on how to solve this. Thank you

Comment: It is unfortunately incorrect.  Within $3^6$ for instance, you are including the constant maps, which does *not* have the *entirety* of $C$ as a subset of the image of $f$.  For a correct approach, let us first assume without loss of generality that $B=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and that $C=\{1,2,3\}$.  Let us count how many of the $4^6$ functions from $A\to B$ are "bad" and miss at least one of the elements of $C$ as being in the image.  Let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be the sets of functions where $1,2,3$ are *not* an element of the image respectively.  The "bad" functions are then $X_1\cup X_2\cup X_3$.

Comment: How big is $|X_1\cup X_2\cup X_3|$?  Think inclusion-exclusion.  How big is $|X_1|$?  How big is $|X_1\cap X_2|$? etc...

Comment: Can you provide me with a final solution so I could see if I got it right?

Comment: I *can*, but I will not.  I can confirm that $969$ is incorrect.  How about you tell me what *you* get following my hint and I'll let you know if it is correct afterwards.

Comment: Is the following approach correct? Number of function that goes only to C is $\frac{6!}{(6-3)!}\cdot 3^3$ and of functions onto B are $\frac{6!}{(6-4)!} \cdot 4^2$

Comment: So the final answer is 9000? @JMoravitz

Comment: There are only $4^6=4096$ possible functions from $A\to B$ and you are looking for *special* functions from $A\to B$ so there must be less than that.  No, $9000$ is incorrect.  And no, your approach is incorrect.

Comment: Oh yeah. Can you explain the inclusion-exclusion approach? I have tried that but didn't realize how to calculate the intersection.

Comment: $X_1\cap X_2$ for example is the set of functions from $A$ to $B$ which contain neither $1$ nor $2$ in the image.  In other words, it is the set of functions from $A$ to $\{3,4\}$.  How do you calculate the number of functions from a six element set to a two element set?

Comment: So $X_1\cap X_2$ is $2^6$ and $X_1$  is $3^6$?

Comment: So by inclusion-exclusion the final result is 2,100. Is that correct now?

Comment: Yes.  $2100$ is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality, let $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, let $B=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and let $C=\{1,2,3\}$.

The total number of functions from $A$ to $B$ can be calculated via [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) by the following steps:

- Choose the value of $f(1)$: there are four options
- Choose the value of $f(2)$: there are again four options
- Choose the value of $f(3)$: there are again four options
- $\vdots$
- Choose the value of $f(6)$: there are again four options

giving a total of $4\cdot 4\cdot 4\cdot 4\cdot 4\cdot 4=4^6=4096$ possible functions from $A$ to $B$.

(*The same argument can be generalized to show that there are $|Y|^{|X|}$ functions from $X$ to $Y$ in general.  It is for this reason that the set of functions from $X$ to $Y$ is sometimes notated as $Y^X$ yielding the nice identity $|Y^X|=|Y|^{|X|}$*)

We are interested in a *special* subset of the functions from $A$ to $B$ with the property that $C$ is a subset of the image, i.e. every element of $C$ is contained in the image at least once.  To calculate this, let us instead remove from our count the number of "bad" functions, namely those functions which are missing at least one of the elements of $C$ from the image.

Let $X_1$ be the set of functions from $A$ to $B$ which does not have $1$ in the image.  Similarly define $X_2$ and $X_3$ to be the sets of functions missing $2$ and $3$ from their images respectively.  The set of "bad" functions then is $X_1\cup X_2\cup X_3$.

The total number of *good* functions then is the total number of functions minus the number of *bad* functions, i.e. $$4^6 - |X_1\cup X_2\cup X_3|$$

Expanding via inclusion-exclusion

$$4^6-|X_1|-|X_2|-|X_3|+|X_1\cap X_2|+|X_1\cap X_3|+|X_2\cap X_3|-|X_1\cap X_2\cap X_3|$$

Calculating each of these terms can be done again by the rule of product using the generalization mentioned above.  For example $|X_1\cap X_2|$ is the number of functions from $A$ to $B$ which does not contain $1$ or $2$ in the image, i.e. the number of functions from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ to $\{3,4\}$.

As found in the comments above, this then simplifies as:

$$4^6-3^6-3^6-3^6+2^6+2^6+2^6-1^6=2100$$